# How to access integer value from a list

Tags: python

```
result = [{'label': 'butterfly', 'confidence': 0.16034618, 'topleft': {'x': 195, 'y': 23}, 'bottomright': {'x': 220, 'y': 45}}, {'label': 'butterfly', 'confidence': 0.27062774, 'topleft': {'x': 64, 'y': 58}, 'bottomright': {'x': 98, 'y': 85}}, {'label': 'butterfly', 'confidence': 0.114007816, 'topleft': {'x': 247, 'y': 191}, 'bottomright': {'x': 268, 'y': 211}}]
```

I want to return only the confidence value from each element.

Comment: `for dict_ in result: print(result['confidence'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
my_list = [
        {
            'label': 'butterfly', 
            'confidence': 0.16034618, 
            'topleft': {'x': 195, 'y': 23}, 
            'bottomright': {'x': 220, 'y': 45}
        }, 
        {
            'label': 'butterfly', 
            'confidence': 0.27062774, 
            'topleft': {'x': 64, 'y': 58}, 
            'bottomright': {'x': 98, 'y': 85}
        }
]

confidence_values = list(
    map(
        lambda x: x['confidence'],
        my_list
    )
)

print(confidence_values)
```